# select statement returning values for non existent value in where clause

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I'm trying the following query in `cql`.

```
SELECT * FROM LoadTest_Storage WHERE ItemName='NDTV_CRICKET145667657568' 
AND key='NDTV_CRICKET1' LIMIT 1000
```

The key is existing but that `itemname` is not there in my table. But still it is returning the data of `NDTV_CRICKET1` key.

But instead of key if i give some other column name for eg.

```
SELECT * FROM LoadTest_Storage WHERE ItemName='NDTV_CRICKET145667657568' 
AND  type='NDTV' LIMIT 1000
```

And such a type exists in my table but the `itemname` is not there then i don't get any results.

Why is it happening for key column alone?

Is it typical behavior of `cassandra`?

Comment: It's not clear enough what the problem is from what you've posted. Try running queries with just `SELECT * FROM LoadTest_Storage WHERE ItemName='NDTV_CRICKET145667657568'` and see if that returns any results. Then use the `DESCRIBE` funtion in cqlsh and please paste the output on the question.

Comment: it is not returning any results if i run the query with ItemName alone. I'm not running the query in cqlsh i'm trying running the query using java code.

Comment: cqlsh / java / any driver, same difference! What is the describe output?